# How does pathVar Attribute of @MatrixVariable annotation works in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was reading regarding the @Matrixvariable annotation in Spring doc [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)

I have Understood this simple syntax
// GET /pets/42;q=11;r=22

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void findPet(@PathVariable String petId, @MatrixVariable int q) {

  // petId == 42
  // q == 11

}
```

but having problem in understanding the below snippet

```
// GET /owners/42;q=11;r=12/pets/21;q=22;s=23

@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void findPet(
        @MatrixVariable Map<String, String> matrixVars,
        @MatrixVariable(pathVar="petId"") Map<String, String> petMatrixVars) {

    // matrixVars: ["q" : [11,22], "r" : 12, "s" : 23]
    // petMatrixVars: ["q" : 11, "s" : 23]

  }
```

What is this syntax @MatrixVariable(pathVar="petId"") 
I haven't understood the pathVar attribute of Matrixvariable annotation?

This line is ok for me   `// matrixVars: ["q" : [11,22], "r" : 12, "s" : 23]` that this variable added with all the matrix variables.
 but how does petMatrixVars added with these Specific values mean

```
//petMatrixVars: ["q" : 11, "s" : 23]  ? why not  //petMatrixVars: ["q" : 22, "s" : 23]  ?
```

Thanks in Advance for your time spent on this thread!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called `Partial Binding` it is used to get all variables from that segment in that path or if you want to get each variable from that path segment [docs](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-matrix-variables), and output is wrong in this documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)

In your example you will get all variables that are in path after `petId` {21}

```
// GET /owners/42;q=11;r=12/pets/21;q=22;s=23
 @MatrixVariable(pathVar="petId") Map<String, String> petMatrixVars)
```

If you want to get only `q` after `petId` segment then

```
@MatrixVariable(value ="q",pathVar="petId") int q
```

Here is the example with output, for `@MatrixVariable` we need to enable them first

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```

Controller with @requestmapping method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void findPet(
        @MatrixVariable Map<String, String> matrixVars,
        @MatrixVariable(pathVar="petId") Map<String, String> petMatrixVars) {
        System.out.println(matrixVars);
        System.out.println(petMatrixVars);
    }
}
```

Request: `http://localhost:8080/sample/owners/42;q=11;r=12/pets/21;q=22;s=23`

Output:

```
{q=11, r=12, s=23}
{q=22, s=23}
```

And if i change `@MatrixVariable Map<String, List<String>> matrixVars,`
the output is

```
{q=[11, 22], r=[12], s=[23]}
{q=22, s=23}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding firstly.  "_In your example you will get all variables that are in path after petId {21}_" then in that case petMatrixVars: ["q" : 22, "s" : 23] is correct not //petMatrixVars: ["q" : 11, "s" : 23]   according to your statement ?

Comment: I check and verified that documentation is wrong regarding values, there is mistake in output values, its working as i said @JAVA